# Problems with the Buttons of the Bottom Bar Toolbar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I am trying to create a toolbar bottom bar like the iPhone Maps app once. The problem is that I have consulted the UICatalog example but I could not find the user location arrow left button and the options curl right button. How can I set my bottom bar buttons with these images?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html

for example, the curl one would be http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I had found the curl one but I can not find the arrow button. I have to use an image to get it?

Comment: did some digging, looks like that's not a system style. This site http://glyphish.com/ looks like it has an image that's exactly like it (in the first set of icons bottom row)

Comment: Yes, but the icon is not free. Is there a free option? If not, I prefer to write something into the button.

Comment: Sorry, I have checked well the free file and it contains the location arrow icon. Thank you Andrew Carter.

Comment: glad you found it! I didn't know if it was in the free pack or not. While you were looking I made you an arrow but I guess you don't need it now :p here it is anyway http://andrewroycarter.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/arrow.png